# reading json from php web service in android

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am using a object I created in my android object to send values as json to my php web service. the sending works well. But after the send I am expected to collect the object back from the web service based on my design which I would now test to be sure that there was a successful post. But I get a funny message in my Log cat as an exception through in my catch statement. I just believe that it as to do with how I am compressing json from my php webservice to android java code.

Exception below
**Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.**

JSON OUTPUT
11-15 07:48:02.622: I/global(276): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
11-15 07:48:02.622: I/output(276):   
11-15 07:48:02.622: I/output(276): **Warning**:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp\www\Rhema\config\config.php:17) in **C:\wamp\www\Rhema\webservice\RegisterMember.php** on line **50**
11-15 07:48:02.622: I/output(276): {"Name":"femi","Username":"dsasdfasft","Phone":"456346345345645","Email":"a@yahoo.com","Submit":"Submit"}

```
My java code below doing the sending


//The first code class is used to represent the json object that would be passed to php
        package com.example.objects;

    public class MemberModel {

        private String Name;

        private String Username;

        private String Phone;

        private String Email;

        private String Submit;

        public void setName(String Name){

            this.Name = Name;
        }

        public String getName(){

            return Name;
        }

        public void setUsername(String Username){

            this.Username = Username;
        }

        public String getUsername(){

            return Username;
        }


        public void setPhone(String Phone){

            this.Phone = Phone;
        }

        public String getPhone(){

            return Phone;
        }

        public void setEmail(String Email){

            this.Email = Email;
        }

        public String getEmail(){

            return Email;
        }

        public void setSubmit(String Submit){

            this.Submit = Submit;
        }

        public String getSubmit(){

            return Submit;
        }   

        //This is going to be used to set the json string notation
        public final static String Member_Name = "Name";
        public final static String Member_Username = "Username";
        public final static String Member_Phone = "Phone";
        public final static String Member_Email = "Email";
        public final static String Member_Submit = "Submit";
    }




    //This is a snippet from the asynctask class that is sending the json object to php
    @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try{
                    JSONHttpClient jsonobject = new JSONHttpClient();
                    model = (MemberModel)jsonobject.PostObject(RestfulUrl.RegisterURL, model, MemberModel.class);

                    Log.i("gothere","here");

                    if(model != null){

                        Log.i("return",model.getSubmit());

                    }   
                    else{
                        Log.i("return","wrong values");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){

                }

                return null;
            }



//The snippet below is the main part of the json object that does the post
//I have tested this with a asp.net mvc app server and it works prity well

 public <T> T PostObject(final String url, final T object, final Class<T> objectClass) {
        DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);



        try {

            StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(object));

            Log.i("jsonobject",stringEntity.toString());

            httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

            HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultHttpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            if (httpEntity != null) {
                InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
                Header contentEncoding = httpResponse.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
                if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                    inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
                }

                String resultString = convertStreamToString(inputStream);
                inputStream.close();
                return new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(resultString, objectClass);

            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.i("a",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.i("b",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("c",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
        return null;
    }

    public <T> T PostParams(String url, final List<NameValuePair> params, final Class<T> objectClass) {
        String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
        url += "?" + paramString;
        return PostObject(url, null, objectClass);
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("first",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i("second",e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }






    //My php code below
     function __construct(){

            $this->connection = new Connector();
            $this->connection->doConnection();


            $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
            $obj = json_decode($json);

            if(isset($obj))
                $this->register($obj);
        }

        function register($obj){

            $name = $obj->{"Name"};
            $username = $obj->{"Username"};
            $phone = $obj->{"Phone"};
            $email = $obj->{"Email"};

            $query = "insert into member (name, username, phone, email,rhemabranchid ) values ('$name','$username','$phone','$email',1)";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

            $id = mysql_insert_id();

            mysql_close();

            if($id >0){
              //  echo "successful";

                $array = array("Name"=>$name,"Username"=>$username,"Phone"=>$phone,"Email"=>$email,"Submit"=>"Submit");

                header('Content-type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($array);
            }
            else
                echo "failed";
        }
```

Comment: THANKS @MT8 I just did that now

Comment: where is json output?

Comment: ohhhhh am coming just a minute

Comment: i have posted now thanks alot

Comment: I removed the leading spaces in my config file. I guess that was what was sending the headers.

Comment: > hi, this link will help for [Android J](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity.getContentLength() != 0) {
    String str = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
    //do stuff
}
```

Use EntityUtils instead of BufferedReader. If your JSON is going to contain only this (even if it does contain more, I work with much bigger JSON outputs), you should be fine via BufferedReader, but I'd consider this just to be on the safe side. Plus, I never have issues this way.

Edit: new to editing in SO...